# Проблема с авторизацией, Laravel PostgreSql

Tags: laravel, postgresql, auth

Делаю приложение на Laravel, используя PostgreSql. Поставил дефолтную аутентификацию. Пользователь нормально регистрируется и авторизируется, а вот с входом возникла проблема. Всё время выдаёт сообщение, что данные не верны, хотя я уверен, что это не так. Достал sql из логов, он выдаёт ошибку. У меня кастомная таблица пользователей, миграцию приложу ниже. В чём может быть проблема?

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->char('login', 30);
   $table->char('email', 191);
   $table->char('password', 191); 
   $table->timestamp('created_at', 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Нужно было в модели User прописать

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
   return Hash::make(request()->get('password'));
}
```

После этого всё заработало как надо